# Which files from phpexcel library are necessary to export data into excel2007 format ? I want minimum number of files

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel_1.7.9 library for exporting data in form of .xlsx format. this library contains 223 files and 53 folders. I want files and folders which are useful for my functionality only (to avoid unnecessary file upload on server).

Bellow is code, working absolutely fine.

```
//----CODE TO EXPORT DATA DIRECTLY AS EXCEL(.XLSX) WITHOUT HELP OF CSV FORMAT ----------  

require_once ROOT_PATH . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

        $header=$exportPlugin->getCommonHeader($case,$frmDate,$toDate,$empid,$divId,$excpCode,$reportType,$varType);
        $data=$exportPlugin->getCommonFilterData($case,$frmDate,$toDate,$empid,$divId,$excpCode,$reportType,$varType);

            $base_path1 = dirname(__FILE__);            
            $lastSpacePosition1 = strrpos($base_path1,"\lib");
            $base_path1 = substr($base_path1,0,$lastSpacePosition1);
            $csvName=str_replace(':','',$csvName);
            $pathh=$base_path1.'\fileexports\\'.$csvName.".xlsx";
            //file_put_contents($pathh, $csvContents);

        $objPHPExcel=new PHPExcel();

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        $alpha=Array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');

        $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

        for($i=0;$igetActiveSheet()->setCellValue($alpha[$i].'1' , $header[$i]);
        }
        $n=3;
        for ($i = 0; $i getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($alpha[$j]. $n, $data[$i][$j]);
                }
        $n++;
        }
        foreach(range('A','Z') as $columnID) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(true);        
        }


        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save($pathh);

        ob_end_clean();     
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. $pathh);
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        readfile($pathh);
        unlink($pathh);         
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please tell me how many and which files or folders from PHPExcel library , should I keep in project and which may I delete ???

working environment-
.......Server - XAMPP
............Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i PHP/5.2.9
............MySQL client version: 5.0.51a
............PHP extension: mysql
.......O.S - WINDOWS7

Comment: While it's not exactly a small package, it's only ~4MB of source files. Why do you care how many files are in it? You'll probably lose much more time trying to dissect this package than any benefit you may gain from doing so is worth.

Comment: deceze , thanks for reply , you are absolutely right but my project leader demanded for it and he is ready to upload maximum 20 to 30 files.

Comment: deceze thanks for reply but will you please remove your last comment ,it is harmful for me???

Comment: Then use the phar distribution, it's only a single file to upload

Comment: ok mark let me read about it

Comment: thanks deceze, for support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely have to do this:

Remove all locale files except those in the /en subdirectory. Remove all named Readers and Writers and associated subdirectories except those you need (you still need the Abstracts and the Interfaces though). Remove all CachedObjectStorage options except Memory/Icache/CacheBase. Remove Charts if you don't use them. Remove Shared PCLZip, OLE files and Escher.... and hope that I've not miscalculated

Comment: ok mark then i will prefer it in that case but first let me try to convince my PL.

Comment: Thanks Mark , your answer was very helpful. My task is complete. thank you once again.